# Different results depending on operating system

Tags: operating-system, fortran, compiler-optimization, compiler-options

I'm using an CFD-code written in Fortran. Some parts of it have been parallelized with OpenMP. Even if I turn of OpenMP and use the same compiler options (-O3) on a Windows an a Linux machine I get different results. After trying to turn off the optimization (-O0) and adding a (-fp-model source) to my compiler options it's only showing NaN after 2 iteration steps. Is there any other reason that there a different results and how can I assure that they're the same)

Thanks,
Sebastian

P.S.: Both machines are using the same Intel Fortran Compiler 2013, are 64 bits and have an Intel Xeon CPU.

Comment: They are diverging on the linux machine while running for 1000 more time steps on the windows machine.

Comment: Hi,
as I've written in my reply to weymouth I found out that the different behaviour is actually caused by the -O3 optimization level. The code is not running with -O0 but with -O1 I was able to generate the same results on Windows and Linux. The divergence is in fact a either a grid problem or due to some (visible) instabilities in the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the algorithm and resolution, it is possible for a bug-free CFD code to get significantly different results by turning on parallelism.

As HPMark suggests, small differences can be expected when changing platforms. Large differences indicate you have some compiler or system-specific code and need work on porting. Getting major problems when you turn DOWN the optimization level might be a memory bug.

Be careful to only change one thing at a time when you get into confusing situations like this.

Comment: I have different results even with parallelism completely turned off. I found out that compiling with -O1 and -fp-model source gave me the same results on both machines. So the more agressive optimisation is responsible for the different results. So I have to think about whether the gain in performance is worth it.